# Запись в файл из консоли (в цикле, построчно)

Tags: c#, файлы

Хочу сделать, что бы каждая строка записывать циклически, в файл. Но, не могу понять почему ничего не записывает, хотя файл создается.
Не до конца понимаю логику, поэтому собственно и не работает. Для полноты понимая, я бы хотел услышать какая логическая ошибка в данном цикле, если конечно он хоть немного правильно написан.

```
        using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {

            while (true)
            {
                StringReader SR = new StringReader(Console.ReadLine());
                if (SR.ReadLine() == "end")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Выход из записи");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(FS);
                    SW.WriteLine(SR.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
```

Так же как я понял, для таких элементарных операций лучше использовать, что то вроде этого `StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)` ?

Answer (score 4):

Запись в файл можно реализовать так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите \"stop\" для прекращения записи в файл.");
    Console.WriteLine();

    using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Новая папка\myFile.txt"))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите текст для записи: ");

            // Читаем текст, введенный пользователем.
            var line = Console.ReadLine();

            // Если ввели stop прерываем цикл. 
            if(line == "stop")
                break;

            // Пишем в файл.
            file.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, вроде помогло хотя все элементарно. Но у меня вопрос, почему записывает пустую строку в конце файла?

Comment: @PavelFedorov когда метод `WriteLine` пишет в файл, он к концу входной строки добавляет набор символов `'\r', '\n'`. Эти символы как раз и означают возврат каретки и новая строка.